# Google Cloud Messaging Registration - Project ID

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to register for using Google Cloud Mesaging in order to use push notifications in my Android app. Using the Google developer console, I tried to create a new project for this. This screen asks for a project name and a project ID. Is it necessary for this project ID to match with the Package Name of my Android app? I tried to do it that way but it complains because my app's package name is longer than 30 characters.

Answer (score 0):

> *This screen asks for a project name and a project ID. Is it necessary for this project ID to match with the Package Name of my Android app?*

No. You just give it the name to easily identify which Project it belongs or which service it uses (e.g. "My Push Notification Project").

With that said, it is no longer possible to create a project for GCM in the Dev Console. You'll have to proceed with creatig a project in the [Firebase Console](https://www.console.firebase.google.com).